# How to create a pdf file that can only be opened by adobe reader using TCPdf and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, adobe, tcpdf

I'm creating a pdf file using PHP/TCPdf, and want the file can only viewed by Adobe Reader.

I want to show the same or some else message:

> To view the full contents of this document, you need a later version of the PDF viewer. You can upgrade to the latest version of Adobe Reader from www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html
>
> For further support, go to www.adobe.com/support/products/acrreader.html

Like these one http://www.kuleuven.be/lucas/Docs/Vacatures/2014_107_ADOCARE.pdf

Can I do that with TCPdf or JavaScript embeddedin PDF?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to require Adobe Reader? For people (such as myself) who use Linux, this is a big problem.

Comment: What feature specific to Adobe Reader do you need? And what about Acrobat? What about use on devices (where Adobe Reader is mediocre, at best)?

Comment: *Like these one* - that PDF actually merely is a container for a XFA form. Its PDF content is that page with "To view ... html" while the job offer is the content of the embedded XFA document. If you want the same behavior, do the same.

Comment: Our clients are government and are all using Windows.Force to use Adobe Reader is for that perfect print effect.

Answer (score 3):

The most common reason for requiring Adobe Acrobat/Reader is the Acrobat JavaScript capability. In this case, Best Practice is to set up the document that it displays the version for a dumb PDF viewer, stating that a smarter viewer is necessary. Then you have a document-level script which deactivates that indication and initializes the document to work with a smarter PDF viewer.

In other words, the approach is assuming that the PDF viewer is dumb, and provide the means for a smart PDF viewer to unlock the advanced features.

For other reasons requiring Acrobat/Reader, such as proper display of overprinting and transparency, it might be necessary to embed the actual document in a wrapper PDF, and have the wrapper export it only when the conditions are fulfilled.

Comment: *The most common reason for requiring Adobe Acrobat/Reader is the Acrobat JavaScript capability.* - or XFA support.

Comment: oh, yeah, XFA… I think that can be handled with the method described in my answer. And think twice if XFA is really, really, really the way to go…

Comment: @MaxWyss: Do you have any code to read xfa from form pdf in php. Please suggest me.

Comment: @Lakhan: Nothing comes to my mind just so. Keep in mind that the form must be an XFA form to begin with. You then should be able to extract the XML part, which you then can parse.

Comment: @MaxWyss : Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @MaxWyss: Yes, you are right. Its in form of xml. But i dont know how to extract that xml from pdf in php. I am using pdftk library which provide me almost all the fields of the form. But not able to extract data in xml format. So, whenever you get something on it then please suggest me. Once again thanks for your reply.